# From Eclipse to android studio internet problems

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

So,I am importing a project that works perfectly (tested on 4 phones) from Eclipse to Android studio and when I run the application WITHOUT modifying anything at all, it won't allow me to use the internet at all.

As for code...it's pointless to post any ,because I created an application that does nothing but connect to a database and it still won't work, while the exact same code will work perfectly when I run the application from Eclipse to my phone. (Same phone by the way)

Just to make sure that won't be an answer: I HAVE the permissions added in my manifest.

Any suggestions?

//manifest.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="vlad.tests.com.udptextconnection" >

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

// Build.gradle (module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vlad.tests.com.udptextconnection"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

//Build.gradle (project [project-name])

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with this?

Comment: What Android Studio version? What happens if you create a dummy project with INTERNET permission and run it on your phone?

Comment: oh no,it's a real device.I tested it on a galay s3 and on a motorola e something that has android 5.0

Comment: If I create a new app on android studio and add perms it's the exact same thing.And I tested it 2 weeks ago not only on a galaxy s3 but on few other phones too...

Comment: Paste here the content of `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest` files from the test project? From the one you've just created. Android Studio can make things messy with its auto-complete.

Comment: I will edit the main question in a moment.

Comment: Edited, check it out.

Comment: All seems OK. Weird I may have to say. I have no other suggestion but either create a new user account and install AS there and run the test project (in case some bug happens inside you own account) or completely remove AS (also `.android` directory) and then install the latest stable build. I have been using AS since 0.1 and not ever had I got such error.

Comment: I know the question might sound weird, but is there a difference between an application that I run from the AS and an application that is published on the store?I'v read some stuff about it but it seemed way ,way too weird...

Comment: Ok so, apparently you don't import a project to AS from Eclipse,you firstly export from eclipse to gradle and AFTER that,you import in AS.I have to run out now,but I managed to import it without errors (after 2 errors while importing) and  I will be testing it as soon as I can get back to it! Be back with news.

Comment: And what if you create à blank project from the studio? Did you try using the emulators web browser ? Are you testing in a real phone, or in a virtual one?

Comment: At least bother reading the freaking question...I said it I tested it to my phone and I said it in comments too...

Answer (score 2):

Try putting permissions outside of application tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it'd work but, try and clean your project.
Go to Build->Clean Project.
Try Build->Rebuild Project.

Comment: See this link if you haven't already:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: I will be checking it in details ,again, but I did go over it already ,without seeing every single detail.

Comment: Just make sure none of the stuff you used is deprecated. And also, does your app compile and run properly?(Except the internet use)

Comment: Yes it does and no,nothing is deprecated.

Comment: A simple way around will be to create a new project in android studio and copy-paste all the files from here to there. Alternatively, please paste your manifest and build.gradle file.

Comment: Alright dude. I just got another idea. Did you try to test on a virtual device? If not then try it. Tell me what happens.

Comment: I won't spend my time anymore on that...it's right down retarded...seriously.I'll keep using eclipse, even though I would love to change to AS, it's simply not going to work for me,for some reasons...tested at least 7-10 things I found,even made a fresh install of AS ,same shit all over again.I find myself really rare to be angry ,but this is the case right now...Thanks for all the help anyways.I'll get back to work, perhaps sometimes next week I'll be willing to waste another few hours on this problem and if I come with an answer,I will post it right away.